# how to load an image using sdl from memory (c++)

Tags: c++, sdl

I have an image inside a `std::vector<std::string>` variable. I downloaded the image from a website using winhttp I successfully managed to write to file and displayed but now I want to display it directly from memory. How can I load it?

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
SDL_Surface *load_image(char * buff,int size) 
{
    SDL_RWops *rw = SDL_RWFromMem(buff,size );
    SDL_Surface *temp = IMG_Load_RW(rw, 1);

    if (temp == NULL) 
    {
        printf("IMG_Load_RW: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Convert the image to optimal display format
    SDL_Surface *myimage;
    image = SDL_DisplayFormat(temp);

    //Free the temporary surface
    SDL_FreeSurface(temp);

    //Return our loaded image
    return myimage;
} 


std::vector <std::string> buffer = c.data();
std::string str_buffer =buffer[0];

for( size_t i =1;i<buffer.size();++i)
{
  str_buffer+=buffer[i];
};

image = load_image(const_cast<char*>(str_buffer.c_str()),str_buffer.length()+1);
```

Comment: your `load_image` routine returns myimage, which is not initialized. Is it just a typo where you really meant `SDL_Surface *myimage = SDL_DisplayFormat(temp);`?

Comment: i dont get what youre saying but it stops at the  printf("IMG_Load_RW: %s\n", IMG_GetError()); line and prints an error so i dont think it have nothing to do with that

Comment: I'm referring to `SDL_Surface *myimage;
image = SDL_DisplayFormat(temp);`

Comment: We need to know what this line means: `std::vector <std::string> buffer = c.data();` Specifically where do you get c from. Follow the data!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure, but it seems that you should simply be able to say this:

```
std::vector<char> the_image; // populate somehow

SDL_Surface * s = load_image(the_image.data(), the_image.size());
```

In older compilers you may have to say `&the_image[0]` for the first argument, in lieu of `data()`.

Comment: thank you ,the .data() didnt work so i used the &_image[0] it compiled but the image wasnt loaded

Comment: Hm, well, your code contains other errors (e.g. `image` is never declared), so it's entirely possible that other things are going wrong elsewhere.

Comment: yes its possible that something goes wrong else where but i wrote the image to a file and displayed it,image is declared i didn't post the whole code (SDL_Surface *image = NULL;)