# SDL draw PNG image from raw image data string

Tags: c++, sdl, embedded-resource, sdl-image

I've setup a PNG resource file in my SDL2 project for Windows 32bit in C++.

```
HRSRC hRes = FindResource(0, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IMGID), "PNG");
if (!hRes) {
    Log::Error("Find resource IMGID");
    return;
}

HGLOBAL hData = LoadResource(0, hRes);
if (!hData) {
    Log::Error("Load resource IMGID");
    return;
}

DWORD dataSize = SizeofResource(0, hRes);
char* data = (char*)LockResource(hData);

std::string result;
result.assign(data, dataSize);
```

The `result` variable contains all the characters of the PNG image (if it was converted to a string).

How can I use this image string with [SDL Image](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/) and display it on the window?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101442/how-to-load-an-image-using-sdl-from-memory-c

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SDL_RWFromConstMem(data, dataSize)`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWFromConstMem) to create a read-only memory-targeted [`SDL_RWops`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWops) and pass that in to [`IMG_Load_RW()`](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/docs/SDL_image_12.html).